# How to make CSS Grid resize the content

Tags: css

I want a column of 4 boxes, that are responsive and also stay in the center of the page, the rest is explained in the comments of the code

I found a solution but it prevents it from being in the center, I included everything in the code i tried.

- This resizes it but it prevents it from being in the center for some reason.

```css
/* THIS RESIZES IT, BUT PREVENTS IT FROM BEING IN THE CENTER FOR SOME REASON */

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "1" "2" "3" "4";
  position: relative;
  top: 25rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.wrap {
  min-width: 30rem;
  max-width: 60rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background-color: #c8e6c9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">1</div>
  <div class="wrap">2</div>
  <div class="wrap">3</div>
  <div class="wrap">4</div>
</div>
```

- this is perfect, but doesn't resize it

```css
/*  THIS IS PERFECT, EXCEPT IT DOESN'T RESIZE IT */

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "1" "2" "3" "4";
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.wrap {
  min-width: 30rem;
  max-width: 60rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background-color: #c8e6c9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">1</div>
  <div class="wrap">2</div>
  <div class="wrap">3</div>
  <div class="wrap">4</div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot.

[How I would like to have it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PefsB.png)

Comment: Just center the container.

Comment: can you also share your HTMl. You want your grid in the middle of the window ? is there anything else ? ..wrap is your four children ?

Comment: i added the html,

Comment: when i use 
align-items: center; 
or  justify-content: center;

nothing happends

Comment: @JCode , wait, i want to use your solution instead, is there a way to disable the horizontal scrolling and keep it in the center?

Comment: @LynxLead I've undeleted the answer. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/bf7Lp6ug/7/

Comment: @LynxLead .. and tell me if it worked for you.

Comment: @JCode this is amazing, thank you so much!! everything is perfect now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a container around it:

```
<body>
    <div class="cntri">
        <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="wrap">1</div>
                <div class="wrap">2</div>
                <div class="wrap">3</div>
                <div class="wrap">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

.wrapper{
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 30rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "1" "2" "3" "4";
}

.wrap{
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    background-color: #c8e6c9;
}

.cntri
{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

Try this fiddle, I think it fits your image:

https://jsfiddle.net/bf7Lp6ug/7/

Comment: thanks, but I meant column and not row, i misspelled that in my post, sorry

Comment: This still works for centering in column really - let me edit it. @LynxLead

Comment: @LynxLead Okay, maybe show us how it looks now and how you want it to look.

Comment: sure, i photoshopped an image that should explain it

Comment: this is great, however, this doesn't resize the box with that space like in the screenshot from Solution1

Comment: @LynxLead It's hard to get what you want, because the code you gave works on its' own. Can you show me how it looks with this solution applied?

Comment: @LynxLead Have you also copied container from HTML code?

Comment: yeah I did, 
its the same "problem" on jsfiddle

Comment: @LynxLead https://jsfiddle.net/vcynrxoa/ Try this, sorry for the mess with links.

Comment: yes, i tried just copying it without changing anything

Comment: well, not quite. its basically the same.  I don't know if i gave up but im thinking of just using the perfect solution 2 and using "@media" to make it responsive

Comment: @LynxLead For me the fiddle: jsfiddle.net/vcynrxoa  looks exacly like the combination of left top image and right bottom.

Do you have bootstrap installed? Because if so, change class of container from "container" to something more unique, because there's already .container in bootstrap that might be why it looks different on fiddle.

Comment: @LynxLead It might not be obvious, but you have to adjust 'max-width' in .wrapper to get it to stretch more - just saying.

Comment: To me it looks like this with max-width: 60rem instead of 30rem: 
https://i.imgur.com/SrqJdqV.png https://i.imgur.com/mmMy1Ez.png

But if this isn't what you wanted (althought it looks to me the same like on your image) then I give up aswell.

Comment: @LynxLead Okay, then take whatever you want from the answer - I'll remove it in a min.

Answer (score 1):

You can use html and body to center your content via flex :

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "1" "2" "3" "4";
}

.wrap {
  min-width: 30rem;
  max-width: 60rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background-color: #c8e6c9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">1</div>
  <div class="wrap">2</div>
  <div class="wrap">3</div>
  <div class="wrap">4</div>
</div>
```